# AndroidStudio Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) nullPointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, calendar, android-studio

I have a problem with my calendar.
Here is the code:

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mToday[0] = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
mToday[1] = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); // zero based
mToday[2] = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Can not run my project because AndroidStudio shows error on the `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`, `Calendar.MONTH` etc... I get nullPointException while running in emulator

It sais that

> Must be one of:
>   java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTHjava.util.Calendar.MONTH etc...

I don't understand this error because `Calendar.MONTH` is one of `java.util.calendar.MONTH`

I have an import for it

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

Sorry I missed that it's initialized but there is an other class where I want to use Calendar.MONTH and so on like this:

```
mCalendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();

...

int dayOfWeek = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int firstDay = getDay(mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

OR

```
private Calendar mCalendarToday;

...

private boolean isToday(int day, int month, int year) {
    if (mCalendarToday.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month
        && mCalendarToday.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year
        && mCalendarToday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == day) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here shows error too. And all the other lines where I would use.

Comment: If you can't build your project, you can't be getting a NullPointerException... which is it?

Comment: I don't understand how you can have NullPointerException when you can't build the project. 

I tried the code in my Eclipse and I had no syntax error. Just a hint for investigation - try to pass 1 instead of YEAR, 2 instead of MONTH and 5 instead of DAY_OF_MONTH.

If you have NullPointerException, then maybe the project was built and run, but the array is not initialized.

Comment: Sorry...

Question has been edited.
I can build but it stops during the run in the emulator.

The problem is not with the int field.

Maybe it's an error in Android Studio i will try it in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug of Android Studio: 0.5.5

see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68758

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that the way you access the calendar is correct.

I'm guessing the `int[]` you try to add the values to is not initialized.
You must call

```
int[] mToday = new int[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoded. But must work.

```
    int[] mToday = new int[]{};
    java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    mToday[0] = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mToday[1] = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
    mToday[2] = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you did not initialize you field. I tried it in Eclipse and this worked

```
int[] mToday = new int[10];
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mToday[0] = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
mToday[1] = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); // zero based
mToday[2] = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```