# calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY gives a lint error

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar, lint

I am using the following code to check if a selected month is January:

```
if (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY) {
    ...
}
```

This gives me a lint error (suppressing it gives "WrongConstant").
There was an [old issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68758) about annotation problems in this area (got there from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243701/androidstudio-calendar-getcalendar-day-of-month-nullpointer-exception)), but it has been fixed in Android Studio 0.5.6 and I'm currently on 2.2.3.

Am I doing something wrong or is this the same (or different) bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face this warning few weeks ago and think it's a new bug in linting system because if you split `get` method call and if statement there is no more warning:

```
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
if (month == Calendar.JANUARY) {
    // We are in January and no warning is displayed!  
}
```

I will use this workaround until a fix will be released in Android Studio...

Comment: It is better than suppressing, I hope they fix it though, thanks!